# Which files to select for installing an old versions of the Azure SDK for .Net

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cloud-services

Downloading a current version of the Azure SDK for .Net is easy to do via the Web Platform Installer tool.

The thing is that it only has the latest 2 versions or so.

If I want to download an older version, Microsoft points me to the [following download site](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/). When clicking download, I'm confronted with a dialog asking me to select which of **20(!)** different files I would like to install.

Of course none of these files have any descriptions, so I'm left to deduce stuff from the file names.
here's the list of all the files i'm seeing for SDK version 2.5

- EnvironmentTools.VS.msi
- HiveODBC32.msi
- HiveODBC64.msi
- Microsoft.Azure.HDInsightToolsForVS2012.msi
- Microsoft.Azure.HDInsightToolsForVS2013.msi
- Microsoft.Azure.HDInsightToolsForVS2015.msi
- MicrosoftAzureAuthoringTools-x64.msi
- MicrosoftAzureAuthoringTools-x86.msi
- MicrosoftAzureComputeEmulator-x64.exe
- MicrosoftAzureComputeEmulator-x86.exe
- MicrosoftAzureLibsForNet-x64.msi
- MicrosoftAzureLibsForNet-x86.msi
- MicrosoftAzureQuickstarts.msi
- MicrosoftAzureStorageTools.msi
- MicrosoftAzureTools.VS110.exe
- MicrosoftAzureTools.VS120.exe
- MicrosoftAzureTools.VS140.exe
- WebToolsExtensionsVS2013.msi
- WebToolsExtensionsVWD2013.msi
- WindowsAzureStorageEmulator.msi

  1. IS there a way to install older SDKs with a single installation (like Web Platform installer)
  2. if not, What is the **minimal** set of programs i need to run in order to successfully build and deploy Azure cloud services? (i don't even need to run it on local emulator). Assuming I have 64 bit machine and VS2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me (on x64 machine and VS2013 install) these are the minimal set of programs i needed to install in order for my build to pass:

- MicrosoftAzureAuthoringTools-x64.msi
- MicrosoftAzureLibsForNet-x64.msi
- MicrosoftAzureTools.VS140.exe (for VS2015) or;
- MicrosoftAzureTools.VS120.exe (for VS2013)

Comment: Why do you have "MicrosoftAzureLibsForNet-x64.msi" twice?

Comment: @DmitryDzygin a typo .. unfortunately I have no recollection of the correct answer so I don't know whether these 2 is enough or a 3rd one is needed. if you find out - do tell and i'll update the answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer I was lacking the first one on one of the machines and it helped to resolve a similar issue